# github.com/shopspring/decimal: different values produced by FromString and FromFloat

Tags: go, decimal

I'm trying to use gomock to mock an interface that takes a decimal. The usecase:

```
v, err := decimal.NewFromString(order.Value)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := p.CDI.CreateBuyEvent(ctx, v); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

And in the tests:

```
value := decimal.NewFromFloat64(1000)
cfg.cdi.EXPECT().CreateBuyEvent(ctx, value).Return(nil)
```

Running this, I get:

```
expected call doesn't match the argument at index 1.
   Got: 1000 (entities.Order)
   Want: is equal to 1000 (entities.Order)
```

However, if I instead instantiate the decimal using `NewFromString("1000")` in the tests, it passes. My question is: why is the underlying value different for `NewFromString` and `NewFromFloat`?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I found this while learning about decimals in go, and you gave me something to lookout for.

Answer (score 1):

Because the two values happen to have different memory representations while *logically* containing the same values.

Use the `Equal` method to compare `shopspring.Decimal` values.

Demonstration:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
)

func main() {
    fs, err := decimal.NewFromString("1000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ff := decimal.NewFromFloat(1000)
    if ff != fs {
        fmt.Printf("%#v != %#v\n", fs, ff)
    }

    fmt.Println(ff.Equal(fs))
}
```

Produces:

`decimal.Decimal{value:(*big.Int)(0xc0001103a0), exp:0} != decimal.Decimal{value:(*big.Int)(0xc0001103c0), exp:3}`
`true`

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SozCPTiQO-U).

---

I would add that there's no need to rush for SO to ask a question like this: you should have first performed at least minimal debugging.
Really, if you have two values which *must* be the same but they do not compare equal using the `==` operator which is dumb — it compares `struct` vaues field-wise, — just see what the values actually contain.

Comment: This doesn't really answer "why" they have two different memory representations.

Comment: @GregGraham, it's hard to answer this in a definitive manner. I could have made an educated guess that it's due to the way those "constructor" function work. But my point is that this simply does not matter: it's clearly an internal repesentation of a particular type which can be anything as long as the type's values behave as documented. What is more, this internal representation is free to change in any way even in minor releases of the package.

Comment: Thank you - that's a good way to put it. The memory representation is an implementation detail that cannot be relied upon by the user. Therefore the Equal method must be used instead of ==.

Comment: @GregGraham, note that those `value` and `exp` fields are unexported anyway; I mean, you cannot refer to them via the usual `.fieldname` notation given a value of type `Decimal`.