# How to test equality of a decimal with stretchr/testify?

Tags: unit-testing, go, decimal

I'm having trouble running a unit test to check if a `decimal` value is what I've expected. This is what I've tried:

```
func Test_example(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("test if two decimals are equal", func(t *testing.T) {
        sum_amount := decimal.NewFromFloat(1000.00)
                          .Add(decimal.NewFromFloat(5000.00))
    
        require.Equal(t, decimal.NewFromFloat32(6000.00), sum_amount))
    })
}
```

As you can see the `sum_amount` is a `decimal`. However comparing the two in the test case work out slightly differently with exponents etc.

How do I properly assert that these values are equal with stretchr/testify?

E.g. here's the diff:

```
Diff:
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ -4,6 +4,6 @@
    abs: (big.nat) (len=1) {
-   (big.Word) 6
+   (big.Word) 6000
      }
    }),
- exp: (int32) 3
+ exp: (int32) 0
  }
```

Comment: A reasonable solution might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71926549/github-com-shopspring-decimal-different-values-produced-by-fromstring-and-fromf) i.e. compare with `decimal.Equal` and assert the resulting boolean

Comment: Thanks man, that's the neatest solution I can think of :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to `decimal.Decimal.Equal` that may work for most cases and still yields an informative error message when the assertion fails - is comparing the string representations of the expected and asserted decimals:

```
require.Equal(t, decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00).String(), sum_amount.String())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `decimal.Equal` so that values can be compared using the library to return a `bool` and then just test if that result is `true`.

Like this:

```
require.Equal(t, decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00).Equal(sum_amount), true)
```

Also instead of comparing two values for equality you can just check that the result is `true` using `require.True`

This is the end result:

```
require.True(t, decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00).Equal(sum_amount))
```

To provide more clarity for interpreting test results, you might add a formatted message, such as:

```
require.True(t, decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00).Equal(sum_amount), "decimal %s != %s", decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00), sum_amount)
```

Comment: I like this approach because it works in a pinch. However it is not ideal, because the comparison is inside the test itself, hence the error message is not going to say the expected variable in the output, it's just going to say that true is not false. So you could do something like:
`require.Equal(t, decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00).Equal(sum_amount), true, "decimal %s != %s", decimal.NewFromFloat(6000.00), sum_amount)`

Comment: Thanks @TomAndersonc :) Feel free to edit my answer to cater for this :)