# Tests fail in Drone CI due to Go & Postgres `wall` mismatch in `time.Time` values

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, timestamp-with-timezone, drone.io

#### The problem

I'm running some database query tests with `testify`.
The tests run in Drone CI by connecting to a `postgres` container running as a `service`.
I consistently get test failures (only in CI, the tests pass when running locally with `dockertest` on a macOS system) when comparing expected & actual values for the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns. Both of these columns are `TIMESTAMPTZ`.
It seems the `wall` values are different between the two, maybe due to Postgres being limited to microsecond precision whereas Go is limited to nanosecond. Please correct me if this is wrong.
What I've seen is the `expected` value look like `630636934` and the `actual` value look like `630636000`, for example:

```
Diff:
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ -3,3 +3,3 @@
CreatedAt: (*time.Time)({
-   wall: (uint64) 630636934,
+   wall: (uint64) 630636000,
ext: (int64) 63845794086,
@@ -33,3 +33,3 @@
UpdatedAt: (*time.Time)({
-   wall: (uint64) 630636934,
+   wall: (uint64) 630636000,
ext: (int64) 63845794086,
```

I am using GORM with the `pgx` driver.

Why am I seeing this error only in Drone CI and not locally? In both cases, `postgres` runs in its own container, though in CI the tests run in a `golang` image and locally they run on a `macOS` system.

#### What I've tried

I've tried creating the database records using `time.Now().Truncate(time.Microsecond).Round(0)`, rather than letting postgres's `DEFAULT now()` run for those two columns, but was still seeing failures when comparing the expected & actual `wall`.
I was calling `.Round(0)` in particular because, according to the godocs, that is how you can strip the monotonic clock reading, but this must not work as I expect since the `wall` values were still present.

I don't understand how I create & store a monotonic-free (supposedly) timestamp, but when it gets retrieved by GORM and compared with the original timestamp, the original `wall` has precision to the last 3 digits, and the actual `wall` always seems "rounded down".

To get the tests passing in CI, I ended up using `testify`'s `assert.ObjectsExportedFieldsAreEqual(...)`, but I'd like to better understand why `wall` differs between `expected` and `actual` and only in CI. Again, I'm not seeing these errors when running the tests locally.
Also, what are the proper terms to talk about the "precision" of this `wall` value?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: To be clear, the question is: Why are the `wall` values between `expected` and `actual` timestamps not matching in Drone CI, but they match locally, and is there a way to have them match in CI?

EDIT2: This is my first SO question. I tried to include as much information as I have as well as what I've tried. Any tips on how to improve the question are appreciated.

Comment: Instead of having testify do the comparison: Just do it yourself and compare e.g. formated timestamps. At least if that's the problem (I'm unsure about what actually you ask or are having trouble with).

Comment: @Volker I'm specifically curious as to why the `wall` values don't match, and if there's anything that can be done to make them match? I feel like comparing formatted timestamps isn't solving the problem as the underlying `wall` values will still likely not match, and I'm not sure why that would be the case in CI and not locally.

Comment: «Why are the wall values between expected and actual timestamps not matching in Drone CI, but they match locally, and is there a way to have them match in CI?»–I'm having troubles fully parsing your question, just like Volker (more on this below) but my take on this particular issue is that either locally the test passes faster or there is some difference in PG confiuration between your local setup and the one in the CI system.

Comment: Look, the wall field is an implementation detail of time.Time. It is unexported for a _reason_. The reason why your timestamps don't match (no matter if this is in wall, ext or loc) cannot be answered from what you have shown. But: Any test that uses "real" time via time.Now is susceptible to fail. In tests you often fake time (to make it deterministic). Note that your manipulation of time.Now's return value makes little sense as monotonic clock doesn't roundtrip via the database.

Comment: Can't you just use [`time.Time.Equal`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Equal) with `assert.True`? You might combine it with fancy printout, like with `assert.True(t, a.Equal(b), "%s != %s", a.Format(time.RFC3339), b.Format(time.RFC3339))`

Comment: @Volker Gotcha - thanks for explaining. Probably multiple layers of things I don't fully understand about the time implementation. I was just confused why, when I explicitly set time.Now(), and store its value, one of the unexported fields (`wall`), changes when I simply retrieve that same value from the database. But it seems like this is just how things are with `time.Time`s. And yet locally this discrepancy doesn't happen. Was wondering if it was an OS-level thing perhaps or something obscure like that, and if anybody had some insight to provide.

Comment: Please note that the docs on `time.Time` explicitly advise against comparing values of this type using the `==` operator (what `assert.Equal` essentially does). `time.Time` is not unique in having this property of possibility of maintaining different internal states exhibiting the same behavior when observed from the outside. Another example off the top of my mind is [an implementation of "decmials" for Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71926682/720999).

Comment: Use [assert.WithinDuration](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.9.0/assert#WithinDuration) to compare times when you don't fully control both values (i.e., if you test that a databases uses sensible defaults). Since you are running tests on someone else's infrastructure, you have no reason to expect the database's clock to be exactly (as in, down to the nanosecond) synchronized to the one running the tests.